# Tracking down a FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net, filenotfoundexception

I have a FileNotFoundException in a DLL.

The exact message is:

> The file or assembly "CefSharp.dll" or one of its dependencies were
>   not found. The module was not found.

Does anybody know how I can find out what exactly the problem is?

I tried using ProcMon, but I am not 100% firm with it, and it could be that I did not use it the adequate way.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to turn on the fusion log and then examine the results. Here's an article that talks about how to do it and how to interpret the results.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: Tried the trial version, would ask me for a log file. Didn't know what it wants. Can you help?

Comment: There is not "trial" version, it's part of the .NET framework. The article talks about how to set up the log file. Please read the article I linked carefully. If you have specific questions (that aren't already answered in the article) I'll try to help.